# Jasmine test for an array keeps failing

Tags: arrays, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write a jasmine test to check if data is entered into an array. I have the view model, the unit (jasmine) test file, and the stage file to set up the information for the unit tests. The error that I am getting is saying that my array is undefined. The error message says "Expected undefined to be {SiteId: 0, FirstName: 'Jon', LastName: 'Walker', ObjectState: 1}"

This is my viewmodel. I am trying to test self.addPatient:

```
var EF = (function () {
    return {
        ObjectState: {
            Unchanged: 0,
            Added: 1,
            Modified: 2,
            Deleted: 3
        }
    };
})();

var patientMapping = {
    'Patients': {
        key: function (patient) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(patient.PatientId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new PatientViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

PatientViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.flagPatientAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }
        return true;
    },
    self.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.FirstName() + " " + self.LastName());
    });
}

SiteViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, patientMapping, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Site/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.siteViewModel != null) {
                    alert("Changes were saved successfully.");
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.siteViewModel, {}, self);
                }
                if (data.newLocation != null) {
                    window.location = data.newLocation;
                }
            }
        });
    },

    self.flagSiteAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }
        return true;
    },

    self.addPatient = function () {
        var patient = new PatientViewModel({ SiteId: 0, FirstName: "", LastName: "", ObjectState: ObjectState.Added });
        self.Patients.push(patient);
    },

    self.deletePatient = function (patient) {
        self.Patients.remove(this);

        if (patient.PatientId() > 0 && self.PatientsToDelete.indexOf(patient.PatientId()) == -1) {
            self.PatientsToDelete.push(patient.PatientId());
        }
    };
}
```

This is my stage file to initialize information for the jasmine tests:

```
//staged data for view model testing

var OBP = OBP || {};

OBP.Testing = (function () {

    var reset = function () {

        var isReadOnly = true;

        window.isReadOnly = true;
        window.ObjectState = 2;
        window.FirstName = "Joe";
        window.LastName = "Mitchell";
        window.SiteId = 5;
        window.patient = { "SiteId": 0, "FirstName": "Jon", "LastName": "Walker", "ObjectState": 1 };
        window.patientDelete = { "PatientId": 1, "SiteId": 0, "FirstName": "Frank", "LastName": "Smith", "ObjectState": 1 };
    };

    return {
        reset: reset
    };
})();

OBP.Testing.reset();
```

This is my jasmine test itself that is failing:

```
/// <reference path="../../lib/jasmine.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../lib/mock-ajax.js" />
/// <reference path="../../jquery-2.1.3.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../../lib/jasmin-jquery.js" />
/// <reference path="../../bootstrap.js" />
/// <reference path="../../knockout-3.2.0.js" />
/// <reference path="../../knockout.mapping-latest.js" />
/// <reference path="SiteViewModelStage.js" />
/// <reference path="../../siteviewmodel.js" />

describe("Add patient check:", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        OBP.Testing.reset()
    });

    var Patients = new Array();
    var viewModel = new SiteViewModel({ patient: window.patient });

    it("Add patient works", function () {
        expect(Patients[0]).toBe(patient);
    });
});
```

Any help debugging my jasmine test would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Patients` is an array of length 0, as defined in `describe()`; it is not passed to any function, and, therefore, it is not modified. `Patients[0]` is then undefined.

Comment: I understand that is where the undefined is coming from but `self.addPatient` has `self.Patients.push(patient);` so I don't understand WHY that is the undefined.

Comment: You have a local variable `var Patients = new Array();` inspected by your test that has no relation with `SiteViewModel .Patients`, the variable use by `addPatient`. On the other hand, you never seem to initialize `Patients` as an array, and calling `push` on it won't work.

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. I got it working now. I will post the corrections so other users can see if they come across this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made Patients and observable array in the viewModel:

```
self.Patients = ko.observableArray();
```

Edited addPatient in the viewModel:

```
self.addPatient = function (patient) {
    self.Patients.push(patient);
},
```

and modified the "Add patient check" unit test:

```
describe("Add patient check:", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        OBP.Testing.reset()
    });

    var viewModel = new SiteViewModel({ patient: window.patient });
    viewModel.addPatient(new PatientViewModel({ PatientId: 1, SiteId: 0, FirstName: "", LastName: "", ObjectState: ObjectState.Added }));

    it("Add patient works", function () {
        expect(viewModel.Patients().length == 1).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

These changes to the viewmodel and unit test solved my problem. From here I am also able to check the name of the patient and do other tests to verify. The explanation from Xv in the comments helped lead me to this solution

Comment: **Jasmine style:** In the test, creating the `viewModel` and calling `addPatient`  belong inside the test or inside `beforeEach`: having it there, in no-man's-land, would give you problems as soon as you added another test. **Stackoverflow style:** Accept your own answer if the question is solved, and up vote comments that have helped you. Cheers!